# Rewrite rules for Anchor CMS on Lighttpd

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, lighttpd

I installed Anchor CMS on my server running Lighttpd, and I am trying to setup pretty url's. I have anchor installed in a sub-directory "/blog".

The htaccess file that works with anchor cms in apache is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

This is the rewrite rule I have in lighttpd:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file += ( "^/blog/(.*)$" => "/blog/index.php/$1")
```

The urls are now pretty, but none of the static content is loading, ie css, javascript and images. I thought using `url.rewrite-if-not-file` would cover this, but it doesn't seem to be working for my installation. http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite#urlrewrite-repeat-if-not-file

The following urls and their files need to be kept intact:

- /blog/themes/default/{ js | css | img }
- /blog/anchor/views/assets/{ js | css | img }

The theme directory can change depending on the theme currently being used. So instead of "default" it could be "example". I am not very good with regex, so I could really use some help. I was thinking something along the lines of this might work:

```
url.rewrite-once += ("^/blog/themes/(.*.)/(css|js|img)/(.*)" => "$0")
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. Lighttpd uses regrex similar to perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with the following rewrite rules:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file += ( "^/(.*)\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif)$" => "$0",
                             "^/blog/(.*)$" => "/blog/index.php/$1" )
```

I hope this helps someone else running anchor cms on lighttpd